# Need a twitter API that gets tweets in a specific location given its coordinates

Tags: java, rest, geolocation, twitter

I am trying to find a Java-based API that can be used with Restful webservices for Twitter that would allow me to get tweets given their location, and their dates..but I am more concerned with searching given their geographical location (latitude and longitude)

I've already been using Twitter's official API, which does what I need except that it doesn't get me any tweets older than 1 week.

Does anyone know any API which could help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you actually can't get tweets older than one week. According to the [official API specification](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) the results you can retrieve entail tweets that are up to 6-9 days old. Please keep in mind that the Search API is not a complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets.

I also assume that you already know how to use the API to get tweets for a given location so I won't explain you that.

What I can suggest though is [reading this article](http://onemansblog.com/2011/04/27/how-to-search-twitter-for-old-tweets-and-how-to-archive-them/) which points at websites like [Snap Bird](http://snapbird.org/) and [Topsy](http://topsy.com/advanced-search). I don't think they have an API that you can use though and they don't do geo-search, so I'm afraid you won't be able to achieve your goal.

Comment: yes, thank you I arrived also to the same conclusion. The tweets older than one week are very hard to get as twitter doesn't provide them and some of the websites or third parties which provide tweets older than one week dont have the option of chossing the location

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions for this is to do local archiving of the results returned from the twitter API calls and save the tweets in database so they will be available in future as old tweets but this will only provide old tweets from the time when the archive will start